# is this html tag structured valid HTML5?

Tags: html

Okay so i've been writing an article in my blog and i often use this tag but i wonder if it's valid HTML5 or not i did search on google but couldn't find the right explanation. i hope i'll find that here. okay the tag structure is below

```
<h1> Heading 1 </h1>
<p>Some Paragraph</p>

  <h2> Heading 2 </h2>
  <p> Short Explanation </p>
   <ul>
    <li> <h3> Heading 3 </h3> 
          <p> Some Explanation
    </li>
   </ul>
```

I wonder if i could wrap Heading 3 inside the li. is it allowed? and is snipped html code above valid HTML5? sorry for my bad english and thanks

Comment: Not without the closing `</p>` for `Some Explanation`.

Comment: @ScottHunter A closing `</p>` is not always required and isn't in this case. See [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) for those instances.

Comment: I'm sorry that's my fault. i write the example manually but in my blog article i didn't miss that part or else it will throw an error LOL and btw i'm using blogger. there's red indicator whenever an error occured. (on html view)

Comment: Blogger templates, last time I looked, used XHTML (mixed with some other name spaces) where end tags *are* mandatory.

Comment: @Quentin yes that's so true. that's why i barely forget the closing tag whenever im doing things there. but in this case i did forget.. i actually forget too sometimes in blogger but since there's a red indicator so i'll know if i did forget to add clossing tag

Answer (score 2):

You can test the validity with tools such as [validator.nu](https://validator.nu/). That code happens to be valid.

Do note, however, that "valid" is just one, basic metric of QA and does not imply "Good" or "Semantically meaningful".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i try it and it's Valid HTML5 but i want to ask do i have to Semantically meaningful my structure tag if it's already valid HTML5? what if i skip Semantically meaningful does it make my website bad? even tho it's valid HTML5???

Comment: Yes, that is what I explicitly said in the second paragraph of this answer.

Comment: OMG i'm sorry i didn't pay attention i actually translate the sentence on google translate and miss the core part. i'm sorry okayy thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. I suppose that there may be different reasons why `<li>` is being used and shouldn't interfere with how the headers are set up.